# Contradiction Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $ (E_j)_{j \geq 1} $ a countable partition of Borel sets of the interval $ [0,1]. $ Assume that $$ \lambda(E_j) = \left|\int_{E_j} e^{ix}\,\mathrm dx\right|,\ \forall\ j \geq 1, $$ where $ \lambda $ is the Lebesgue measure on $ \mathbb{R}. $  We want to reach a contradiction. My attempt for the case when $ E_j $ are subintervals of $ [0,1], $ was successful. In fact, if $ E_j = (a_j,a_{j+1}), $ the it yields $$ (a_{j+1} -a_j)^2 = (\sin a_{j+1} -\sin a_j)^2 + (\cos a_{j+1} - \cos a_j)^2 \Rightarrow \frac{(a_{j+1} -a_j)^2}{2} = 1- \cos(a_{j+1} -a_j) = 2 \sin^2 \left(\frac{a_{j+1} -a_j}{2}\right). $$ Hence, $ \frac{a_{j+1}-a_j}{2} = \sin (\frac{a_{j+1} -a_j}{2}),\ \forall\ j. $ Having in mind that $ 0 < a_{j+1} -a_j \leq 1, $ we can conclude that $ a_{j+1} -a_j = 0,\ \forall\ j, $ which leads to a contradiction. But, for the general case, it looks more complicated.

Comment: In fact in the general case you can show that $\lambda(E_j)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$ \lambda (E_j)= |\int_{E_j} e^{ix}dx| \leq  \int_{E_j} |e^{ix}|dx =\lambda (E_j)$.This implies that $e^{ix+ia}$ is real and  $\geq 0$ almost everywhere on $E_j$  or $e^{ix+ia}$ is real and  $\leq 0$ almost everywhere on $E_j$ for some real number $a$  which implies that $\lambda(E_j)=0$ for each $j$. Of course, this contradicts the fact that $(E_j)$ is partition of $[0,1]$.

Lemma

Let $f$ be  a complex valued bounded function and $\mu$ be a positive finite measure. If $|\int fd\mu|=\int |f|d\mu$ then , for some real number $a$, $fe^{ia}$ is real valued and non-negative a.e. or  it is real valued and non-positive a.e. [Geometrically this means that almost all values of $f$ lie in a ray thorugh the origin in the complex lane].

Proof: Let $\int f d\mu=re^{it}$ with $r \geq 0, t\in \mathbb R$. Then $r=\int e^{-it}fd\mu$. This implies that  $$r=  \int \Re [e^{-it}f]d\mu \leq \int |e^{-it}f|d\mu$$ $$=\int |f|d\mu=|\int fd\mu|=r.$$ It follows that $$\int \Re g =\int |g|d\mu$$ and hence $\Re g=|g|$ a.e. where $g(t)=e^{-it}f(t)$. But then $\Im g=0$ a.e. Rest should be clear.

Comment: why $ e^{ix} $ is necessarily real and positive almost everywhere on $ E_j $ ?

Comment: @SemiMath I have added a proof of that fact.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much. But, I have some comment concerning the lemma and its proof. In fact, I think that it is not necessarily that $ f $ is real valued but it should be of the form $ f(x) = e^{-it} \vert f(x)\vert,\ \forall\ x $ where $ t $ independent of $ x. $

Comment: @SemiMath You are right. I have edited.